# Python cv2 imwrite stops saving after a few iterations

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a script to iterate through a series of folders containing images, stack those images vertically, and save the result.

The issue is that it works for the first two folders and then stops saving the image. `cv2.imwrite` fails silently so I'm struggling to find what exactly is causing the issue, notably the images are still stitched together and look perfectly fine using `cv2.imshow`, and again the stitched image is saved perfectly fine in the first two loops.

The code is as follows:

```
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import join

# Designates the main directory where all the subdirectories with images are
path = 'Folder_Name'

for folder in listdir(path):
    # Designates each subdirectory
    cpath = f'{path}\\{folder}'
    print(f'Combining {folder}')
    images = []
    for file in listdir(cpath):
        img = cv2.imread(join(cpath, file))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)

    vert = cv2.vconcat(images)
    cv2.imshow('combined_image.jpeg', vert)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    out = f'{path}\\jpegs\\{folder}.jpeg'

    cv2.imwrite(out, vert)

    print(f'\tSaved {folder} to {out}')
```

The code outputs `folder1.jpeg` and `folder2.jpeg` in the JPEGs folder but `cv2.imwrite` fails after that.

I've also tried using an absolute path to see what happens with `cv2.imwrite` at each iteration, but curiously after the 2nd iteration `cv2.imwrite` just deletes it, as in `test.jpeg` will appear as `folder1.jpeg` on the first iteration, `folder2.jpeg` on the second, and then gets deleted.

There are roughly 200 iterations to go through.

Comment: When `imwrite` fails, it should return `False`. I don't see any check for that -- is that what's actually happening?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the combined image for the cases where it fails? Since you're stacking vertically, the height would be the relevant one. JPEG stores the image dimensions as unsigned 16-bit integers, so if the height is greater than 65535 pixels, it's impossible to encode the image. Try a different format -- PNG uses 32-bit sizes, so that should work.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes it was failing, I didn't include the check in the consolidated code. I converted the image to Pillow to try saving there and that gave me a useful error when trying to save, the JPEG size limit was the issue. Saving to .tiff solves the issue. Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an X-Y problem — it's not the number of iterations that's the cause of the problem, it's the cumulative height of the images in each directory. The first two directories just happened to have few-enough images to work.

You're saving the images in JPEG format, and according to Wikipedia (and the standard but it's rather tricky to find it there) *"JPEG/JFIF supports a maximum image size of 65,535×65,535 pixels"* — i.e. the dimensions are stored as unsigned 16-bit integers.

Now, it's quite likely (and you confirmed that in a comment) that the combined height of the images in those subsequent directories exceeds the maximum size that JPEG supports. In this case `cv2.imwrite` would return `False` to signal the failure (and in a comment you mention this was the case).

The solution in this case is simple: use an image format that supports the size of images you want to save. In this case you could use PNG, or TIFF (as you tried), or perhaps some others that OpenCV supports.